# Home router DNS sending scrambled IPs

Tags: networking, router, dns

My network is behind a Technicolor TG582n provided by my ISP, it seems as if the firmware was modded to change some branding stuff and hide some features, but nothing much apart from that, I think. The problem is that by checking the DNS entries (via telnet) I can see the following:

```
{ISP}=> dns server host list
Address                                         Type Hostname                     TTL (s)                          Creator
192.168.1.103                                 * A    android-563cbc8707b8b48            0                      DHCP_Server
192.168.1.104                                 * A    android-724e830e4f3ce335           0                      DHCP_Server
192.168.1.107                                 * A    android-d01c6d882f6ab824           0                      DHCP_Server
```

However if I test some of the entries with `nslookup` I get this:

```
$ nslookup - 192.168.1.254
> android-563cbc8707b8b48
...
192.18.10.163
```

When it should be `192.168.1.103`, as if the digits were scrambled somehow. It even fails with custom entries, I get:

```
> test
...
192.1.106.118
```

Instead of `192.168.1.1`, so what could be the problem here? Is this feature broken on this brand and model or did my ISP really mess up the router's firmware?

**Edit:**

Also note that names like `google.com` work perfectly fine, i.e. for that name I am getting `216.58.193.46` as a response from the router and the address is correct.

Comment: What DNS server is the machine doing the `nslookup` using? Check in case its more than one. - I have just moved one of these routers so I may be able to check with a UK version in the next day or 2.

Comment: @user3788685 the machine is using the home router's built-in DNS server at the gateway address `192.168.1.254`.

Comment: do you get replies from either the valid or invalid addresses when pinged ?